# Yii 2. Replace "+" in URL to "-"

Tags: php, url, yii2, yii-url-manager

**What do I want**

I want to replace "+" in URL-attrib to "-". I'm using Yii 2.

***I want working URLs with "-". URL::to(...) generates URL with "-". I want user to see in his browser address panel with "-".***

*Example*:

This

```
 <siteneme>/hospital/U.S.A./Cleveland+Clinic
```

To this

```
<siteneme>/hospital/U.S.A./Cleveland-Clinic
```

**What do I have**

Here is my `web.php`

```
 'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl'     => true,
            'showScriptName'      => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules'               => [

                //Site controller, hospital action
                'hospital/<location>/<name>' => 'site/hospital',

                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'               => '<controller>/<action>',

                //removing 'controller' form URL
                '<alias:index|search|detail|result|hospital>' => 'site/<alias>',
            ],

        ],
```

*This is how generates URL in view* :

```
   <?= Url::to([
                'hospital', 
                'location' => $item->locations['name'],
                'name'     => $item->attributes['name'] ]); ?>
```

Comment: I guess you mean `<siteneme>/hospital/U.S.A./Cleveland-Clinic`?

Comment: @Tom yes, of course. Thank you)

Comment: You need to be more specific about your request. Do you want to create new URL with - instead of + or do you want to redirect user to URL with - when he puts + or maybe you want to get - instead of + in the controller's action?

Comment: @Bizley updated. I want my app work the same way, but see "-" instead of "+"

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get it. If URLs are generated with - and user sees address with - what is the problem?

Comment: @Bizley I ***want*** that, but now there are "+". I want ***to replace them*** . It's ok) Maybe that's because I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Ok, better now. Can you add an example of how you generate the URL that comes up with `+`?

Comment: @Bizley updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` is generated because of urlencoding the space character.

If you want to only change `+` to `-` you can do something like that:

```
<?= Url::to([
    'hospital', 
    'location' => str_replace(' ', '-', $item->locations['name']),
    'name'     => str_replace(' ', '-', $item->attributes['name'])
]); ?>
```

This will change every space  in name to `-` (in the example here both location and name is changed) and urlencoded `-` is not modified.

Comment: Ahahahahaha...the ansver is soooo obvious and my question is so stupid) Thank you)